# Problem with asynchronous behaviour in flutter and firebase combination

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, dart, firebase-authentication

I have a stream-builder that listens to changes on the authentication state.
When a user successfully log's in i want to check wether or not his email address is admin@admin.de ( I am creating the users with admin and password )
To do that i have a async function that queries firebase for the current user and gets the email.
I then compare the email with my example email but it doesn't work, infact it always endup at the AuthScreen() which should only be visible when you login or when you log out.

```
Future<String> check_for_privilege() async {
  final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  final String email = user.email.toString();
  return email;
}

class _MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  Future<String> email;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
          builder: (ctx, userSnapshot) {

            if (userSnapshot.hasData) {
              check_for_privilege().then((value) {
              if (value == 'admin@admin.de'){
                return AdminPanelScreen();
              }
              else {
                return StoreListScreen();
            }
              });

            }
            return AuthScreen();
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Edit:

As Julian Otto pointed out correctly the AuthScreen() is called in any case. But putting it in a condition like

```
Else if (userSnapshot.hasData == null) {
return AuthScreen()
}
```

results in the following error:

This function has a return type of 'AuthScreen', but doesn't end with a return statement.

Edit 2:

```
class _MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  Future<String> email;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
          builder: (ctx, userSnapshot) {

            if (userSnapshot.hasData) {
              check_for_privilege().then((value) {
                if (value == 'admin@admin.de'){
                  return AdminPanelScreen();
                }
                else {
                  return StoreListScreen();
                }
              });

            }
            else{
              return AuthScreen();
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

this is the error
[image]

Comment: There is no need for you to put an `else if`, just use the `else`

Comment: has the same result :/

Comment: But you took off the condition, right? The `(userSnapshot.hasData == null)`? It should just be `else {  return AuthScreen(); }`

Comment: yes but i still get this error This function has a return type of 'AuthScreen', but doesn't end with a return statement.

Comment: Can you please show your updated code in the edit.

Comment: i edited my post and included a screenshot of the error message

Comment: It is giving `but doesn't end with a return statement. ` because you are not returning anything in the first *if*, using that future function, and checking where to navigate will give you this behavior. I advise you to adopt the first answer you got or try something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should create an else part for the `if(userSnapshot.hasData)` in which you return AuthScreen when the userSnapshot (the user) doesnt exist yet. From just looking at it i assume no matter if the first `if` has data or not you always return the AuthScreen.

I would do it this way assuming userSnapshot.data is FirebaseUser:

```
if (userSnapshot.hasData) {
  if (userSnapshot.data.email == 'admin@admin.de'){
       return AdminPanelScreen();
     } else {
       return StoreListScreen();
     }
} else  {
return AuthScreen();     
}
```

Also you use `userSnapshot.connectionState` or `userSnapshot.data.connectionState` i dont remember quiet to display for example a Progress Indicator

Comment: i can confirm your observation i just tested it. do you have a solution for this? if i try you solution i get the following error: 
This function has a return type of 'AuthScreen', but doesn't end with a return statement.